# Where did Merge go in Raster menu?

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I am using QGIS 3.6.2-Noosa. Last time I merged rasters (a couple of weeks ago) I had options on the Raster Menu that are mysteriously gone now (I would merge via Raster>Miscellaneous>Merge). Now when I click on the Raster menu I have only two options: Raster Calculator... and Align Rasters...

I am not aware of having updated QGIS and cannot find documentation of Merge on QGIS' website. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The Merge tool is also in the Processing Toolbox, so you may be able to access it through the Processing Toolbox.

If you can't open the Processing Toolbox panel, then you must have deactivated the Processing plugin (probably by accident, although this does seem to happen occasionally for no apparent reason).

**Re-enable the Processing plugin through the Plugin Manager.**

[image]